# ClusterExport of large objects in Parallel package

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I have a data table of 6.5Gb. I would like to do some parallel computations in a loop with `ParLapply` (e.g. running regressions). At the moment, when I try `clusterExport` in the parallel package, it takes ages (I have never seen it finish exporting it).

I have 16 cores and 64Gb of RAM. Is it normal? How could I speed up the export of the large data table?

```
num_cores = (detectCores(all.tests = FALSE, logical = TRUE) - 2)
workers <- parallel::makePSOCKcluster(num_cores, useXDR=F)
for(pck_name in required.pck){ 
  clusterExport(workers, c("pck_name"), envir = environment())
  clusterEvalQ(workers, library(pck_name, character.only=TRUE))
}

# Bit that freezes up 
clusterExport(workers, varlist = c("big_data_table"), envir 
= environment())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of exporting the in-memory object, consider saving it to disk (using `save` or `saveRDS`) and then loading it into the worker processes.

Note also that whichever way you do it, you'll end up with a separate 6.5GB object in each worker process. With 16 cores x2 for hyperthreading (which you're using with `detectCores(logical=TRUE)`), that's 32 - 2 = 30 processes. So you don't actually have enough memory for all those data tables.

Comment: So you mean that the best approach would be set `detectCores(logical=FALSE)` and then load the `big_data_table` inside the `parLapply`? And even in that case, given that I have only 64Gb of RAM, I won’t probably be able to run more than 6-8 threads for this [so `workers = 6`?]?

Comment: You should set the number of  workers to whatever fits into the memory you have. Don't forget that any other stuff you're doing (including background services) will also use memory

Comment: I dont know if this applies to you. Whenever I have large dataset, I usually "sparisfy" the dataset by representative sub-setting of the data or performing unsupervised dimensionality reduction.  You can always perform it in chunks. Wrap a lapply around a parLapply.